# Git: How can I exclude certain files from a remote branch and include them in another?

Tags: git

I have a config file committed to a private remote repository (AKA private).  Now I want to share my project with others.  They will have access to a different remote repository (AKA shared).  **I do not want the people who look at shared to be able to see this config file.**

1. I want to be able to develop on one branch locally, but be able to push to private and shared.
2. I don't want the shared to contain the history of this file whatsoever.  I imagine I'll have to rebase it out.
3. I still want to be able to periodically push commits to both.
4. Ideally, I would like to avoid `push -f`'s.

Does Git provide a mechanism to do this?

Comment: So this config needs to be tracked but should not be visible to anyone ? is that what you mean ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 not exactly.  It needs to be tracked in one remote repository but not another.

Comment: Then having a separate gitignore for that remote repo can help.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to keep a file out of a branch is to never commit it there, and never rebase the branch on any other branch where that file exists. This is the only way to keep it out of the history.

Consider working on the branch where this file is never committed, and only pushing this branch out to the shared repository.

Then, open another branch, where the non-shared file is committed, and it exists. Then, keep rebasing *that* branch onto your publicly-available branch.

If you need to do test something out with the non-public file, you'll have to switch to that branch, rebase on the head of your main development branch, then when done, switch back to the main development branch, where that file does not exist. Essentially, your private branch will always be one or more commits ahead of your main development branch, with the extra commits being the history of changes to the non-public file.

It's going to be a little bit of a pain, but this is pretty much the only way I can think of to do something like this. If you intend to go this way, I strongly recommend installing a commit hook (see git documentation) that will check and make sure that the non-public file does not ever get committed accidentally to the main development branch. It's not likely to happen, but is a safety net. The most common mistake I could see happening is forgetting that you have the private branch checked out, and making some commits there.

If you realize that this happen, do NOT go back to the main development branch, and attempt to rebase it onto the private branch. That will pull the file into the main development branch's history. Instead, carefully cherry-pick commits from the private branch, to bring the main development branch up to date.

Answer (score -1):

use this tutorial to remove the file from your repo 
https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

then use git-crypt to keep the config file encrypted but still tracked by git https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt

Comment: Unfortunately, this information does not really answer the question.